# django models ForeignKey on_delete set custom default

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model `subscription` where the class is defined as below,

```
class Subscription(TimestampedModel):
    ...
    notification = models.ForeignKey(
         'settings.NotificationPreference', on_delete=models.SET(get_default_reminder), null=True
    )
    ...
```

I would like to set the `default notification: id` if the foreign model is deleted, Upon some research found the `set` method which could be used to achieve the same, referring https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET I could understand the implementation, However i am now stuck as the default notification is going to be per user based. My `get_default_reminder` function is as below,

```
def get_default_reminder():
    return NotificationPreference.objects.get(user_id=user_id, name='Default Notification')
```

The problem here is I do not understand how to pass the `user_id` to get the user specific default notification id.

Comment: You don't, since this is a callable that does not take items, and is furthermore request-unaware.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what would be the best work around, I am thinking to have on_delete SET_NULL here and in the `NotificationPreference` serializer have a check  of this in the delete function

Comment: why set it to refer to an object. If you set it to `NULL` you can implement for example a property that in case of `NULL` will calculate the `NotificationPreference` of that user. The nice thing is that if later you change the preference of that user to another object, the subscription is "automatically" also updated so to speak.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i got an idea, Could you point me to some doc where i could understand the implementation a little better, I am sorry i am somewhat new to Django. Also i feel another challenge here, The default `NotificationPreference` must not delete.